# Symfony\Component\Locale\Stub\StubIntlDateFormatter::__construct() method's argument $locale value 'en_IN' behavior is not implemented

Tags: symfony, translation, symfony-sonata

I am getting this exception, its one of the known issues and as suggested I have installed `php5-intl` via apt-get and restarted my **Nginx** server.

Nothing seems to work out.

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("The Symfony\Component\Locale\Stub\StubIntlDateFormatter::__construct() method's argument $locale value 'en_IN' behavior is not implemented. Only the 'en' locale is supported.
>
> Please install the 'intl' extension for full localization capabilities.")
>   in SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig at line 4.

Comment: I did sudo apt-get install php5-intl to install the extensions. Restarted nginx and cleared symfony cache as well but nothing seems to work out.

Comment: Have you tried with a different locale? Maybe `en_US`...

Comment: If you have standard edition try to run `php app/check.php` which check if you have installed intl properly. See https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/app/check.php

Comment: Thanks Florent, I3I0. Sorry for getting back to you guys a bit late. I tried with en_US but it dint work. app/check.php shows everything ok as expected.

Comment: @l3l0 should be right. The problem is not the php extension which should be installed in anyway. The Symfony component should fix the issue: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/intl.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guys revisiting this issue, Team faced the same issue, we tried installing `php5-intl` extension and restart `nginx` & `php5-fpm`.

It didn't work. But we did a system restart the issue was gone. So one more weird answer. But worked for me.

Comment: php5-intl extension is required anyways in case it does not work try above trick.

Comment: Encoutered on OS X 10.10 Yosemite with native PHP Engine. `icu` installation OK, `intl` PHP extension installion OK, `php -m | grep 'intl'` gives back `intl` as expected, but still the same error. A reboot did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

These are simple steps to install the `intl` on Mac OS X:

1. `brew install icu4c`
2. `sudo pecl install intl`

   The path to the **ICU libraries** and headers is: `/usr/local/opt/icu4c/`
3. Edit `/etc/php.ini` and find and uncomment

   ```
   ;extension=intl.so
   ```

   or add

   ```
   extension=intl.so
   ```

   to the end of file.
4. Create new page and put

   ```
   <?php phpinfo();?>
   ```

   in to see if **Intl** is installed successfully or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on my local OSX setup, which uses homebrew.

I had installed intl and it was showing up when I ran php -v, so I didn't understand where the problem was coming from.

Turned out that the php version apache was using was different from the php version cli was using. So make sure to check out php -v AND run a phpinfo() through your browser, when verifying if your intl extension is enabled.

In my case, the LoadModule directive in my apache's httpd.conf had changed. I ran **brew info php54** to get the right LoadModule to put in my httpd.conf.